# Pass sed output to mv

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm trying to batch rename text files according to a string they contain.
I used sed to isolate the pattern with `\`( and `\`) as I couldn't get this to work in grep.

```
sed -i '' 's/<title>\(.*\)<\/title>/&/g' *.txt | mv *.txt $sed.txt
```

(the text I want to use as filename is between html title tags)`
Where I wrote $sed would be the output of sed.

hope that's clear!

Comment: Take a loog at xargs(1).  It's designed to do the sort of thing you want.

Comment: post the filenames you want to rename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple loop in bash can accomplish this.  If each file is valid HTML, meaning you have only one `<title>` tag in the file, you can rename them all this way:

```
for file in *.txt; do 
    mv "$file" `sed -n  's/<title>\([^<]*\)<\/title>/\1/p;' $file| sed -e 's/[ ][ ]*/_/g'`.txt
done
```

So, if you have files `1.txt`, `2.txt` and `3.txt`, each with `cat`, `dog` and `my hippo` in their TITLE tags, you'll end up with `cat.txt`, `dog.txt` and `my_hippo.txt` after the above loop.

**EDIT:** quoted initial `$file` in case there are spaces in filenames; and added a second `sed` to convert any spaces in the `<title>` tag to `_`'s in resulting filenames. *NOTE* the whitespace inside the `[]`'s in the second `sed` command is a literal `space` and `tab` character.

Comment: Two remarks, if I may: 1) the `\`command\`` syntax tends to be deprecated, maybe you'd better use the `$(command)` syntax in answers instead; 2) you may want to surroud `$file` as well as your `sed` expression with quotes, to prevent spaces from breaking your `mv` command.

Comment: Good point on the spaces in filenames, I've edited to take that into account. However, I use the `backticks` as opposed to the `$()` syntax because the OP didn't mention what shell they were using and the `$()` is only available in `ksh` or `bash` related shells and not others.

Comment: I thought about that possibility, then wrote that anyway because you did mention *bash* in your post (also, OP used `bash` tag, but I hadn't noticed either when I wrote previous comment).  Thanks for adding the quotes, anyway :)

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what (and how) I was trying to do!

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose expression in grave accent characters (`) to make it insert its output to the place you want. Try:

```
mv *.txt `sed -i '' 's/<title>\(.*\)<\/title>/&/g' *.txt`.txt
```

It is rather not flexible, but should work.

(I haven't used it in a while and cannot test it now, so I might be wrong).

Comment: Be very cautious with this. If the files 'a.txt' and 'b.txt' are found, then this gives "mv a.txt b.txt 'sed...  a.txt b.txt'.txt". Read about xargs or about loops in Bash.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Definitely true.. This is just a quick and dirty solution.

Answer (score 0):

What I read from your question is:

1. you have a number of text (html) files in a directory
2. each file contains at least the tag `<title> ... </title>`
3. you want to extract the content (elements.text) and use it as filename
4. last you want to rename that file to the extracted filename

Is this correct?

So, then you need to loop through the files, e.g. with xargs or find

1. `ls '*.txt' | xargs -i\{\} command "{}" ...`
2. `find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' -exec command "{}" ... \;`

I always replace the xargs substitues by `-i\{\}` because the resulting command is compatible if I use it sometimes with find and its substitute `{}`.

Next the -maxdepth option will help find not to dive deeper in directory, if no subdir, you can leave it out.

`command` could be something very simple like `echo "Testing File: {}"` or a really small script if you use it with bash:

`find . -name '*.txt' -exec bash -c 'CUR_FILE="{}"; echo "Working on: $CUR_FILE"; ls -l "$CUR_FILE";' \;`

The big decision for your question is: how to get the text from title element.

1. A simple solution (suitable if opening and closing tag is on same textline) would be by grep
2. A more solid solution is to use a HTML Parser and navigate by DOM operation

The simple solution base on:

1. get the title line
2. remove the everything before and after title content

So do it together:

`ls *.txt | xargs -i\{\} bash -c 'TITLE=$(egrep "<title>[^<]*</title>" "{}"); NEW_FNAME=$(echo "$TITLE" | sed -e "s#.*<title>\([^<]*\)</title>.*#\1#"); mv -v "{}" "$NEW_FNAME.txt"'`

Same with usage of find:

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' -exec bash -c 'TITLE=$(egrep "<title>[^<]*</title>" "{}"); NEW_FNAME=$(echo "$TITLE" | sed -e "s#.*<title>\([^<]*\)</title>.*#\1#"); mv -v "{}" "$NEW_FNAME.txt"' \;`

Hopefully it is what you expected.

Comment: Thanks! I read somewhere yesterday that it was a bad idea to use ls for anything else than displaying information so I was trying to stay away from that alternative :)

Comment: That was a joking comment :-) `ls` is often your friend. be sure that substitution with houndres of files may break `ls *.txt` because it break the argument buffer. in such cases you have to use `find`. I edit the answer and add the construct with `find` for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the command I would use:

```
for i in *.txt ; do
    sed "s=<title>\(.*\)</title>=mv '$i' '\1'=e" $i
done
```

The `sed` substitution search for pattern in each one of your `.txt` files. For each file it creates string `mv 'file_name' 'found_pattern'`.
With the `e` command at the end of `sed` commands, this resulting string is directly executed in terminal, thus it renames your files.

Some hints:

1. Note the use of `=`s instead of `/`s as delimiters for `sed` substition: it's more readable as you already have `/`s in your pattern (you could use many other symbols if you don't like `=`). And in this way you don't have to escape the `/` in your pattern.
2. The `e` command for `sed` executes the created string.
   (I'm speaking of this one below:

   ```
   sed "s=<title>\(.*\)</title>=mv '$i' '\1'=e" $i
                                             ^
   ```

   )
   So use it with caution! I would recommand to first use the line without final `e`: it won't execute any `mv` command, but just print instead what *would be* executed if you were to add the `e`.

Comment: Thanks! This works great without the "e", but I get an error message when I try with it. (bad flag). Seems like there's no such thing in the osx sed...

Comment: @user3741713 Ah, sorry. I did not know that :( (if it worked, the `e` command should be described in `sed` man page, if you ever want to check for it).